# MongoDB removing array variable

Tags: mongodb

```
db.categories.remove(
{"categoryId" : 510001,"name" : "Nevresim Takımları"},{
productTypes:{$elemMatch:{name:"Seri Sonu Ürünler"}}})
```

I used this for

```
"_id" : ObjectId("57e6fb9ca71845002b9be169"),
    "_class" : "net.infoowl.hepsiburada.microservice.product.domain.Category",
    "name" : "Nevresim Takımları",
    "categoryId" : 510001,
    "parentCategoryId" : 9010109,
    "productTypes" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57e6fa87e0c6de002c209124"),
            "name" : "Seri Sonu Ürünler",
            "requiredHeaders" : [ ],
            "uniqueConstraints" : [ ],
            "fields" : [ ],
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-24T22:13:27.882Z"),
            "createdBy" : "user-0",
            "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2016-09-24T22:13:27.882Z"),
            "modifiedBy" : "user-0",
            "extend" : DBRef("productTypes", "base")
```

to delete that `"seri sonu ürünler"`

but it all deleted

```
"categoryId" : 510001,"name" : "Nevresim Takımları"
```

why?

When i did find, it found correct variable in array but when remove, why different?

```
db.categories.find({"categoryId" : 510001,"name" : "Nevresim Takımları"},{productTypes:{$elemMatch:{name:"Seri Sonu Ürünler"}}}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e6fb9ca71845002b9be169"),
    "productTypes" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57e6fa87e0c6de002c209124"),
            "name" : "Seri Sonu Ürünler",
            "requiredHeaders" : [ ],
            "uniqueConstraints" : [ ],
            "fields" : [ ],
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-24T22:13:27.882Z"),
            "createdBy" : "user-0",
            "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2016-09-24T22:13:27.882Z"),
            "modifiedBy" : "user-0",
            "extend" : DBRef("productTypes", "base")
        }
    ]
}
```

this is for remove

db.categories.remove(

```
{"categoryId" : 510001,"name" : "Nevresim Takımları"},{
productTypes:{$elemMatch:{name:"Seri Sonu Ürünler"}}})
```

this is for find
d`b.categories.find({"categoryId" : 510001,"name" : "Nevresim Takımları"},{productTypes:{$elemMatch:{name:"Seri Sonu Ürünler"}}}).pretty()`

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. What are you trying to do what is the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`remove`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) is used to remove full documents from the collection using a given query. Your query returned this document so it was all deleted.
If you want to delete an element from an array inside a document, you need to use [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

In you case, you would want to do it like this:

```
db.categories.update(
    {
        "categoryId" : 510001,
        "name" : "Nevresim Takımları"
    },
    { 
        $pull: {
            productTypes: {
                name: "Seri Sonu Ürünler"
            }
        }
    }
)
```